# POST duplicate entry not causing PK collision in Spring Data REST

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

As per [Spring Data REST Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_post), POST method creates a new entity from the given request body. However, I found it could also update the existing entity. In some cases, this can be problematic. Here is an example:

DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, String> {}
```

User.java

```
package com.example;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private String username;
    private String password;
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

pom.xml (within project tag)

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

application.properties: empty

URL: http://localhost:8080/users

Method: POST

JSON content:

```
{"username":"user","password":"password"}
```

I assumed the above POST request was getting HTTP 201 at the first time, and only for one time. However, I was able to send the above POST request many times, and got HTTP 201 all the time. In addition, I was also able to change the password in the database using POST request.

I believe that this is a security problem. For example, I might allow anonymous user registration through a POST request. But, with above situation, the existing user could be overwritten.

> **Question:** How can I prevent a new entity being created from a POST request if an old entity has already existed with the same id? Or, did I miss interpret the Spring Data REST Documentation?

**Supplementary explanation:**

The cause of this issue is the design behind Spring Data REST. Because Spring Data REST is built upon Spring Data JPA, which was not used to directly expose to the “outside”. So it “trusts” data that comes in. The method isNew in [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractEntityInformation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/2.0.x/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/AbstractEntityInformation.java) shows how data is determined as new or not new.

```
public boolean isNew(T entity) {

    ID id = getId(entity);
    Class<ID> idType = getIdType();

    if (!idType.isPrimitive()) {
        return id == null;
    }

    if (id instanceof Number) {
        return ((Number) id).longValue() == 0L;
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Unsupported primitive id type %s!", idType));
}
```

The result of isNew method will eventually effects save method in [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/2.0.x/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java).

```
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

In the situation mentioned in this question, the username field, which is also the id of the user entity, would always contain data in order to create new users. Therefore, when it goes to isNew, id == null will always return false. Then save method will always perform a merge operation.

The above hints are all I can provide. Even though, I do not know if there is a solution to solve this problem.

*URL links are just references. They may be not the exact the same version to what I am using.*

Comment: Even if it wasn't the PK/ID, you would still have to validate prior to add/edit to catch duplicates. Right? So write a validator. http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-validators

Answer (score 0):

To make an entity work properly with Spring Data REST (and Spring Data JPA as well), the entity class needs to implement Persistable. The more noticeable method to be overridden is isNew(). This method will be called instead of the one in AbstractEntityInformation mentioned in the question. To make an entity knowing its own state (new or old), a version variable is also needed. By annotating @Version on an explicit field, Spring Data JPA will update this field. Thus, once the entity is first constructed, the field is it’s default value (null or 0 depending on what data type it uses). In addition, because Spring Data REST is meant to expose to the outside world, to protect version from being misused, @JsonIgnore is used on version field.

For this particular question, the User.java class needs to be changed to as following:

```
package com.example;

import javax.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class User implements Persistable<String> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7509971300023426574L;
    @Id
    private String username;

    private String password;

    @Version
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long version;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return version == null;
    }
}
```

As @Alan Hay mentioned, validation should also be performed for the incoming data. It is definitely good to have.